# Kusto: Full table scan on join even join conditions are time-based?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto Query like:

```
(Events
| take 1)
| join kind=leftouter Sensor_Data on $left.start_timestmp == 
$right.timestmp, someotherfield
```

and it will never return. The right side of the join has several billion entries.

If I do a

```
Events
| take 1
```

and use the result in the where clause of Sensor_Data it returns in no time.

The MS Support Team explains that this query requires a full table scan of the Sensors_Data table. The join parameters are not taken into consideration by the query optimizer.

Question:
Is the Kusto Query Optimizer really no able to optimize queries based on the join condition? To me it sounds a little bit like 1999 to have to first do the left side of the query manualy and then do the right side manualy as well? Is there some hint or so, to make this run fast?

Answer (score 0):

consider rewriting your query as follows (for example) and see if that helps it perform better:

```
let x = toscalar(Events | take 1 | project pack("ts", start_timestmp, "sof", someotherfield));
Sensor_Data
| where timestmp == todatetime(x["ts"])
| where someotherfield == tostring(x["sof"])
```

Comment: Hello Yoni... This query returns in 0.108s. The "problem" is, that we want our users to use KQL to drill into the data in a "self-service" manner. Do you know of any documentation which we can hand over to them when to use joins, and what is prohibited? The original query, when used in a SQL database context returns in no time as well... The MS performance tipps just mention to use the smaller table as left side...

Comment: Best practices are available at https://aka.ms/kusto.query-best-practices

Comment: Thank Yoni, but as it seems to me none says none covers best practices for joins to avoid full table scans (we do a join on time, so we use a time filter; left size is smaller than right size...)?